# Python Esri Arcpy Compare geometry from Polygon and Polyline

Tags: python, polygon, polyline, arcpy, arcmap

I have two layers on ArcMap:

- Layer A Geometry Polygon.
- Layer B Geometry Polyline (close).

I want to compare each record of layer B with the outline of layer A.
Layer B (Polyline) has the lines that surround the polygon (side dish).
I must therefore compare that the line B is the boundary of the polygon A with Python 2.7 and ArcPy.

If I convert the first Polygon in Polyline to have two Polyline layers:

```
arcpy.PolygonToLine_management("inLayerPolygon", "outFeaturePolyline", "IGNORE_NEIGHBORS")
```

can I compare the Shape fields?

```
#LIST LAYERS ON THE MAP
for lyr in arcpy.mapping.ListLayers(self.mxd, '*'):             
  self.listLayer[lyr.name] = lyr.dataSource   
  
LayerP = 'LayerA'
LayerB = 'LayerB'
dsLayer = self.listLayer.get(layer, 0)  
arr = arcpy.da.FeatureClassToNumPyArray(in_table= ds, field_names= ["ID", "SHAPE"])                     
for row in arr:
  cursor = arcpy.da.SearchCursor("LayerB", field_names= ["ID", "SHAPE"], where_clause = "ID = " + str(row[0]))
  for r in cursor:
    if row["SHAPE"] == r["SHAPE"]:
      arcpy.AddMessage('YES') 
    else:
      arcpy.AddMessage('NO')
```

Answer (score 1):

I found this solution :

```
#LIST LAYERS
for lyr in arcpy.mapping.ListLayers(self.mxd, '*'):             
    self.listLayer[lyr.name] = lyr.dataSource   
    
    desc = arcpy.Describe(lyr.dataSource)
    arcpy.AddMessage("Feature Type:  " + desc.featureType) 
    arcpy.AddMessage("Shape Type :   " + desc.shapeType) 
    arcpy.AddMessage("Spatial Index: " + str(desc.hasSpatialIndex)) 

layer1 = 'LayerA' (Polyline)
layer2 = 'LayerB' (Polygon)
newLayer = 'newLayer'

ds1 = self.listLayer.get(layer1, 0)
ds2 = self.listLayer.get(layer2, 0)

geodb = 'C:/GEODB/chk.gdb'
arcpy.MakeFeatureLayer_management(ds1,newLayer)

# Select all cities that overlap the chihuahua polygon
arcpy.SelectLayerByLocation_management(newLayer, "BOUNDARY_TOUCHES", ds2, "", "NEW_SELECTION")

num = arcpy.GetCount_management(newLayer)
arcpy.AddMessage("num = " + str(num)) 

# Write the selected features to a new featureclass
arcpy.CopyFeatures_management(newLayer, geodb + "/newfc")
```

I want to get the NOT selected features

Answer (score 1):

This is a better solution

```
arr = arcpy.da.FeatureClassToNumPyArray(in_table= ds, field_names= '*', where_clause= sWhere)

for row in arr:

    if arcpy.Exists(fcLayerPolyline):
        arcpy.Delete_management(fcLayerPolyline)

    if arcpy.Exists(fcLayerPolygon):
        arcpy.Delete_management(fcLayerPolygon)

    arcpy.MakeFeatureLayer_management(dsPolyline, fcLayerPolyline, "ID_GMO = " + str(row["ID"]))
    arcpy.MakeFeatureLayer_management(dsPolygon, fcLayerPolygon)

    #Seleziono Poligono ST011PAT
    arcpy.SelectLayerByLocation_management(fcLayerPolygon, "SHARE_A_LINE_SEGMENT_WITH", fcLayerPolyline, "", "NEW_SELECTION")

    num = arcpy.GetCount_management(fcLayerPolygon)

    
    with arcpy.da.SearchCursor(fcLayerPolygon, ['TIPO']) as cursor:
        for r in cursor:
            if r[0] == row["TIPO"]
                ....
```